# How can I get section titles show first letter capitalized?

Tags: beamer, xetex, errors, compiling

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

%\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort  &  compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!70!black}

%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

%\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{fg=red,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
%\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=green!50!blue} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

%\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=green,bg=red!10} 

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}
\begin{document}
  \logo{%
         \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{logo}%
     }
\begin{frame}{}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{ Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I use above command for my `beamer`-presentation and after compilation the letters on the title of section are all capitalized! For example this command gives me a slide with section title `"INTRODUCTION"`, but I want to have `Introduction` because I write 'Introduction'. I don't know which package it is!

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean the frame title. The command

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}
```

sets the shape of the frame titles to SmallCaps. So you probably just want to remove this line.

Comment: @maedeh If Benjamin's answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check-mark on the left.